# Display json data in PHP from API using GET

Tags: php, json, api

I have API url looks like this:
https://api.domain.demo/v1.1/employees/1?api_token=123456

when I click on it I got the following data:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Anna"}
```

How to display and format the response data in PHP page using GET method?

Comment: you have to use json_decode(the url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_decode()` is what you are looking.

```
$link = "your url"

$data = json_decode($link,true);
```

after decoding the json, you will get a array with the elements in the json

```
print_r($data)
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way:

```
<?php
        $url = "https://api...";
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
        echo "id: ", $data['id'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo "Name: ", $data['name'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo "Logo: ", '<img src="', $data['logo'], ' " height="30" width="30">';
?>
```